# Adding a bottom border to nav links without pushing down its parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a nav menu that I'd like to add a 3px solid border on hover to its li elements. The problem is when you hover over these li's their border pushes down their parent container div with a 1px solid border. What would be the best approach to keeping both the nav menu and its parent container on one plane while the nav's border overlays the  bottom border of the container? (Please note the comments are just there to remove the extra spacing in between the inline-block elements).

**HTML**

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>!--
   --><li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;}
nav li {display: inline-block; list-style: none;}
nav li a {color: #999; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 15px 10px 15px; text-decoration: none;}
nav li a:hover {border-bottom: 3px solid #e32b21; color: #e32b21;}
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem, thank you for asking this !!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could displace it with a transparent border.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/gxukz/)

```
nav li a {
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a negative margin of 3px on `:hover`

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/gxukz/1/)

```
nav li a:hover {
    margin-bottom:-3px;
}
```

I'd go with the first solution.

Comment: First option seemed to work. Any idea how overlay the parent div so that it would cover its bottom border? I would think that I'd have to set the ul's position to relative and then have it top: 1px. Didn't know if that would be the best solution.

Comment: @CarlEdwards If i'm understanding you correctly, you want something like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/gxukz/2/ .. ? Basically, just set `ul { padding:0; margin:0; }`

Comment: @JoshCrozier Thank you I've been trying to find a solution to this for ages, you solved it in a really easy and smart way

Answer (score 4):

This would give you what you want, even though it's using box-shadow instead of border. But it's a quick and simple fix.

```
nav li a:hover { 
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #e32b21; 
}
```

Another option would be to just add 3px less to your element , which you had 10px before, so make it 7px, might do the trick

```
nav li a:hover {
     padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```